# Orthodontist charged me more than submitted as total to insurance and wants me to pay the rest?

Tags: united-states, insurance, health-insurance

I had an orthodontic  procedure done. The total bill was $10k.  My insurance covers 90% of this procedure.They  processed the claim and it shows coverage  at about 60% of the total amount.

I called the insurance company and they said that the dentist  has a set fee for this procedure.  It is NOT $10k but $8k so we will cover 90% of that amount.  So where did that extra $2,000 go to?

The contract says that I am responsible for what the insurance does not pay but what do I have to do with what he charged them or gets for some contract fee?

So now I am responsible for that $2k  plus  10% of the covered amount of $8k?  This is very misleading and feels like a scam.

How do I get the orthodontist  to rebill the insurance for the full amount of $10,000  so that my bill is the expected $1k? Or if the total amount is $8k  then how do I get my total bill adjusted to the correct total amount? Otherwise what's the point of having insurance cover something at a certain rate if they can add on whatever they want?

**EDIT:**
Maximum ***covered*** is 15k for this procedure and have never used any of this benefit

Provider is In-Network

Comment: When you had your initial consultation, you should have been presented with a cost for services and if you agreed to that amount, treatment would begin.  How much was THAT amount?  (not the billed amount or the insurance coverage amount).

Comment: Why does the insurance company believe that this orthodontist typically charges 8K? What's their source? Once they present you with that info contact the orthodontist and ask him to clarify why he charged 2K more than normal. Have him share that information with the insurance company.

Comment: @Dugan - The ins company has no belief as to what the dentist charges. They have a payment schedule for services rendered. A non participating dentist (out of network) can charge whatever he likes for services. Scheduled coverage by  insurance company for the ortho treatment is $8k with a 10% patient copay or $800. If $10k then the patient would be  responsible for the total difference ($2,800). There's no impropriety there. There would be if an in network dentist was attempting to charge more than the $8k amount.  The real problem is what did the patient agree to before treatment was begun?

Comment: @Bob Baerker OP says "[the insurance company] said he [(OP's orthodontist)] has a set fee for this procedure and it is NOT $10,000 but $8,000". In understand your point, but it seems that something different may be going on here.

Comment: @Dugan - There are two likely possibilities.  (1) Patient misunderstanding and he owes the $2,800 for agreed upon services, not realizing that insurance company has schedule maximum (905 of $8k) or (2) An in network dentist is overcharging (what you are alluding to).  The insurance company cannot dictate what the set fee is for a non participating member.

Comment: @bob-baerker: It does have the 8K amount on one of the pages. I missed it. But it shows it as what is covered by insurance, makes it sounds like that is the max insurance will cover. Insurance said my max is 15k for this. I see that I have signed it but this is messed up...and sounds like he should not be doing that since he is in network. Max covered is 15k for procedure. It sounds like I have 2 problems, I signed to pay the extra 2K (but was mislead) AND an in-network is overcharging.

Comment: @GregMcNulty Okay, so if I'm reading your edits correctly, when you look at your explanation of benefits (EOB) from your insurer it shows that the dentist billed them $8,000. But the bill you got from the dentist says that the total is $10,000. Is that correct?

Comment: @nosjack: Yes, it is billed at 8k on the claim. I told them I was charged 10k and they said yes "we see that" but his "fee" for the procedure is at 8K ....so that what the whole claim must go by. That is far as I got because I didn't understand what was left or right.

Comment: @Greg McNulty - It sounds like you're getting more clarity but it's still a contradiction of sorts. If he's in network, he's contractually bound to charge you $8k. If he's out of network and you signed, it's a contract and you are liable for the difference. You should contact the orthodontist (or his insurance employee) as well the insurance company to work this out.  Down the road you can avail yourself of  Peer Review  at the local county dental society (if there is one) and they may be able to  resolve your complaint. Don't waste their time unless the complaint is legitimate and provable.

Comment: @bob-baerker , Thanks....."If he's in network, he's contractually bound to charge you $8k"...this is NOT the case. The totals do not match. Ok I think I will notify the insurance...see what they can do first.

Comment: @bob-baerker: really good info here, may want to formulate below as an answer...

Comment: Usually dental insurance has an annual maximum, which is the maximum the insurer will pay in a year.  This is different than an annual maximum under medical insurance which is typically the maximum out of pocket for the member.  What bob is saying is completely accurate, in-network providers, are generally barred from balance billing under their network contract.  SOME will still TRY.  BUT, you may have exhausted your dental insurance maximum, which puts you on the hook for the balance.  It's not really clear where the details fall in your question.

Comment: @Greg McNulty - I typoed  up above and wrote (905 of $8k) when I meant 90%.   I doubt that was critical to understanding my comment but just in case, I'm  mentioning it. The initial reason that I refrained from an answer wass because as quid suggested, it wasn't clear where the details fall in your question.  The back and forth in the comments have fleshed out some of them  so an answer at this point would be superfluous.

Comment: @quid: understood. Yes I have a specific seperate maximum for this and have never used it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Answer was edited based on OP's edits and comments, see the bellow for the original answer)

You said that the orthodontist billed insurance $8k, so insurance paid based off of $8k (all is good).Then you got the bill from the orthodontist and they said the total amount is $10k (uh oh).

In other words *the orthodontist charged you more than what they charged insurance.* You should contact the orthodontist and have them explain why they have two amounts for the same procedure. You can even tell them "I called my insurance and they said you have a set fee of $8,000 for this procedure and that is what you billed them for. I will only pay my coinsurance based on that amount".

---

By the way,

> The contract says that I am responsible for what the insurance does not pay

is 100% normal and does not mean the orthodontist is trying to screw you. This simply protects them from the people that don't understand coinsurance/copays and say "I have insurance so I shouldn't have to pay anything!". **But**, if the orthodontist is in-network and they charge you more than the contract amount, that's a problem!

In your case you can demand that you will only pay based on $8,000 since *that's what they told your insurance the procedure cost.*

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

The insurance company has a "book" of covered procedures and the acceptable fee for those services. If a medical provider is in the insurance company's network, then they agree to accept the amount given in the "book" as payment in full for the service. This is called the "negotiated", "contract", or "covered" amount.

**If they are out of network**

The insurance "book" says that your procedure should cost $8,000. But, your orthodontist is not in their network so he doesn't have to abide by that rate. So he bills insurance $10,000 and they say "we will only cover 90% of $8,000". This means you pay 10% copay on $8,000 and then the *full amount above $8,000.* Or `0.1*8000 + (10,000 - 8,000) = $2,800`

**If they are in network**

The orthodontist can still bill as much as they want ($10,000) but then insurance will come back and say "you are in network and the contract amount for this procedure is $8,000". The orthodontist should then send you a bill like this:

```
Procedure cost: $10,000
Insurance negotiated amount: $8,000
Insurance payed: $7,200
YOU OWE: $800
```

TL;DR

The orthodontist can bill insurance whatever he wants, but if he is in-network then he must abide by their "negotiated" rate. Contact your insurance or login to your online account and figure out if the orthodontist is in-network.

- If he is not, then everything is as it should be (assuming the math checks out).
- If the orthodontist *is* in network, you should contact your insurance
  and tell them an in-network provider is charging you more than the
  negotiated amount.

Comment: If the provider is out of network, you can (and should) press them hard on the $8k vs $10k difference and see if they will negotiate. The insurer stating that their rate is $8k is a pretty good sign that the industry, at large, is accepting of an $8k rate for that procedure.

Comment: @nosjack: ok, interesting and that is what I was also thinking. Yes, he is in-network. Im looking at the paper work in detail (should have done that there) and I sign that I would pay any amount not covered. In one page it shows that my insurance will cover only 8,000 but it makes it sounds like a max covered by insurance NOT a contract price. The max is really 15k. Very deceiving. Guess i will let the insurance call them out on it for now...unless I am screwed by sign the trick contract.

Comment: @GregMcNulty Does the bill have anything regarding a contract or negotiated amount? The $15,000 might be your max out-of-pocket. Does it only list one procedure with a single $10,000 cost? It is possible that the orthodontist billed insurance for multiple things, one of which is not covered by insurance. i.e. $8,000 surgery (covered, you pay 10%) + $2,000 fee for anesthesia (not covered, you pay 100%).

Comment: @nosjack: Hi, It's a one item claim. Confirmed with ins its the Max coverage amount.

Comment: @GregMcNulty I have changed my answer based on your edits and comments. Let me know if I misunderstood what you said.

Comment: @nosjack: thanks for the updates. I contacted insurance, they said my only responsibility is 10% the contracted rate for this service. I called the ortho office and now they are saying there are extra "record" fees, blah blah blah...that response right there confirmed to me they are charging me more...uggg.

Comment: @GregMcNulty I would expect "record fees" to be a separate line item on the claim AND on the bill you received from them. They are essentially not billing insurance for something and making you pay it directly. Ask them to either submit a new claim with correct line items, or an additional one for the "record fees". (Also, $2k for "record fees" is ridiculous. If I were you I wouldn't go back to this orthodontist again...)

Comment: @Nosjack And I would let the insurance know what happened.  They're not going to like that!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, insurances agree with the doctors on a defined amount for a procedure - and the doctor accepts that, that is what in-network means.

if the doctor bills a higher amount than that agreed amount to the insurance, they will just discard the remainder, and ignore it - after all, the doctor agreed to not charge more, period.

if you agreed with the doctor that he charges the higher price, it is now your responsibility to pay the difference (yeah, ugly).
The question would be - *did you agree?*

You should have gotten a detailed cost and execution plan, in written, from the doctor, before the activity started. If this showed the higher price, and you signed it, then you accepted it (and you have to pay the remainder). 
If that plan does not show the higher price, or you never signed a plan, the doctor would have difficulties to force that money from you.

Either way, most doctors are willing to negotiate with you, and if he got 6000+ from the insurance, he is probably willing to waive the remainder.
Call them, and explain nicely that you didn't understand that, and have huge difficulties to pay the remainder, and ask if there's any way they could waive it. Important: be nice and ask for their help, don't *request*.

Comment: This isn't accurate.  It doesn't matter if the patient agrees, the provider's network agreement prohibits balance billing, period. This issue here that's still unaddressed by the question is the annual maximum on the dental plan, because this additional $2k might not actually be a balance bill.  This might simply be the remainder of the covered amount in excess of the annual maximum, which is relatively common in dental programs.

Comment: I would assume that depends on the contract and the network, and is not a general limitation. At least I see it all the time, and when I tell my doctor 'you can't bill me the balance', he says 'watch me!'.

Comment: You are injecting uncertainty in to a part of this system that is not uncertain.  You definitely do not see in-network *doctors* routinely balance billing in-network patients.  You see out of network providers do that.  And physical therapy and chiropractors and other non-doctor in-network providers may try to balance bill.  And this isn't a medical insurance issue, this is a dentist, dental insurance, and orthodontia benefit.

Comment: @quid: yes, way under the maximum. the ortho office is say its record keeping fees now and "special" lab fees. Umm no, that is standard part of the related services.

Comment: @aganju: the only reason I signed it is based on how they worded it at the time and I didnt not read what my benefits were before I went in....very ugly.

Comment: @GregMcNulty Be sure to let the provider know that you intend to file a grievance with your insurance company because they did not adequately inform you of these charges and they are not customary. Point out that you specifically chose an in network provider to avoid unexpected additional charges and point out that you will point that out to your insurance provider.